# Cucumber: @SmokeTest Tagging one scenario out of a scenario outline

Tags: java, cucumber, tagging, scenarios, smoke-testing

I am new to tagging in Cucumber.  I have built up an automation suite and have identified all tests which can be effectively tagged as Smoke Tests using the @SmokeTest tag.

However is there a way to do the following?  I don't want to tag the whole of the Scenario Outline as a SmokeTest - but just want one test/response to be the Scenario as per below:

**What I don't want - as this will test all scenarios**

```
@SmokeTest    
Scenario Outline: Number is or is not valid
    Given I send an event with the "Number" set to <num>
    Then I will receive the following <message>
    Examples:
        | num    | message           |                                                                                     
        | 0      | "Processed event" |                                                        
        | 1      | "Processed event" |                                                                  
        | 2      | "Processed event" |                                                                 
        | 3      | "Processed event" |                                                                 
        | 4      | "Processed event" |                                                                 
        | 5      | "Processed event" |                                                                                                                                 
        | 6      | "Message failed"  |
        | -1     | "Message failed"  |
        | "One"  | "Message failed"  |
```

**What I would like to have - using the Number of 1 as tagged as my Smoke Test**

```
Scenario Outline: Number is or is not valid
    Given I send an event with the "Number" set to <num>
    Then I will receive the following <message>
    Examples:
           | num    | message           |                                                                                     
           | 0      | "Processed event" |                                                        
@SmokeTest | 1      | "Processed event" |                                                                  
           | 2      | "Processed event" |                                                                 
           | 3      | "Processed event" |                                                                 
           | 4      | "Processed event" |                                                                 
           | 5      | "Processed event" |                                                                                                                                 
           | 6      | "Message failed"  |
           | -1     | "Message failed"  |
           | "One"  | "Message failed"  |
```

Is this possible?  Or would it be better to create a separate scenario definition with the Smoke Test I just want?

Many thanks!

Kirsty

Comment: Split the table into two and provide the required tag on top of the examples keyword containing the smoke scenario..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tag examples sections and have multiple examples sections.

```
@SmokeTest    
Scenario Outline: Number is or is not valid
    Given I send an event with the "Number" set to <num>
    Then I will receive the following <message>
  
    @SmokeTest
    Examples: 
        | num    | message           |                                                                                     
        | 0      | "Processed event" |   

    Examples: You can also name these 
        | num    | message           |                                                                                                                                          
        | 1      | "Processed event" |                                                                  
        | 2      | "Processed event" |
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you for this clean approach!! :)